# Reading variables when they're initialized

Tags: java

Although this is a newbie question, I was confused on how the value of the variable is read?

```
int a = 7;
```

would it be left to right or right to left?

also this:

```
//X is a supper class of Y and Z which are sibblings.
public class RunTimeCastDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
            X x = new X();
            Y y = new Y();
            Z z = new Z();
            X xy = new Y(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
            X xz = new Z(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
            //      Y yz = new Z();   incompatible type (siblings)
            //      Y y1 = new X();   X is not a Y
            //      Z z1 = new X();   X is not a Z
            X x1 = y; // compiles ok (y is subclass of X)
            X x2 = z; // compiles ok (z is subclass of X)
            Y y1 = (Y) x; // compiles ok but produces runtime error
            Z z1 = (Z) x; // compiles ok but produces runtime error
            Y y2 = (Y) x1; // compiles and runs ok (x1 is type Y)
            Z z2 = (Z) x2; // compiles and runs ok (x2 is type Z)
            //      Y y3 = (Y) z;     inconvertible types (siblings)
            //      Z z3 = (Z) y;     inconvertible types (siblings)
            Object o = z;
            Object o1 = (Y) o; // compiles ok but produces runtime error
        }
    }
```

I don't get how the superclass = new subclass is read

```
 X xy = new Y(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
    X xz = new Z(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
```

(Why would it be up the hierarchy, if X is the superclass of them? should it not be down?)

Comment: The thumb rule is you can always use supertype variable to refer a subtype object.

Comment: How is it read? You have two choices: either a = 7, or 7 = a. In Java you can't reassign a primitive integer, so only one way makes sense, no?

Comment: thank you @DaveNewton but what if you're dealing with Object assignments to variables? Do the same things apply?
EX:
Superclass X = subclass Y;
can it be read as X = subclass Y
or Y = Superclass X?

Comment: @muddayard ... Assignment is assignment, regardless of the type(s).

Answer (score 2):

> ...how the value of the variable is read?

For an `=` (assignment) operation, the value on the right is evaluated and stored into the variable on the left. So in your example, the `7` is evaluated first and stored into `a`. If the right hand side was more complicated, it would be evaluated left-to-right before being stored into the variable on the left.

> Why would it be up the hierarchy, if X is the superclass of them? should it not be down?

It is permissible to store a subclass as its superclass because the subclass implements all the functionality of the superclass. So, if `X` defines method `Test()`, and `Y` is a subclass of `X`, then `Y` implements the method as well. So you can have an instance of `Y` and store it in a variable typed for `X` because all of `X`'s functionality is available in `Y`.

Comment: okay, that did clarify it for me, however, I am a bit confused on this: (referring back to the code above)

 X xy = new Y(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
What does it mean when xy is 'type' X but refers to object Y?
Can xy access all of object Y's methods or do they require casts?

Comment: For `X xy = new Y()`, you wouldn't be able to call `xy.YMethod()` without a cast because `xy` is the `X` type. The `Y` object isn't modified when it is stored into an `X` variable, but the case is required because you could also do, for example, `X xy = new Z()`, where `Z` is also a subclass of `X`. If you then tried running `((Y)xy).YMethod()`, the cast would fail because the object itself is a `Z`. So I rambled on a bit, but in short, yes, if an object is stored as its supertype, then you'll need to cast it to the subtype if you need to access any subtype's methods.

Comment: so in order for the variable to access the object's method, it would have to be the same type too (without using a cast)?
Y xy = new Y(); xy.YMethod(); 
this would require no cast but this would?:
X xy = new Y(); ((Y)xy).YMethod();

Comment: Yes, that's it! The variable needs to be of a type that knows about the method, otherwise you'll get a compile error.

Comment: @Fls'Zen :D thank you for your help! I actually understood your explanations unlike my textbook >_>